# Winform : How to show error icon on empty fields?

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.Net application with forms with some bound fields.

When I type some wrong data in fields, the ErrorProvider shows a red ico automatically.

Is there any way that it shows the same icon when some required fields are empty ?

Here is the binding code of my controls :

```
Dim MyDataTable as datatable = GetDT
Me.Control.DataBindings.Add(New Binding(Me.BindingProperty, MyDataTable, FieldName, True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation))

Function GetDT() As DataTable
    Dim DT As New DataTable

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    DT.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("C1", i.GetType))
    DT.Columns(0).AllowDBNull = False

    Dim R As DataRow = DT.NewRow
    R.Item(0) = 15
    DT.Rows.Add(R)

    Return DT
End Function
```

The method **ErrorProvider.SetError** is not an option since the controls are created in a separate process and do not have access to the ErrorProvider.

Thanks.

Comment: `controls are created in a separate process`  Huh?  Why would that prevent you from using the SetError option?

Comment: Controls are created in a separate project. They are integrated later in the main project to the main form which contains the ErrorProvider

Comment: So after they are added, perform the SetError on those controls.

Comment: Well, it's little bit more complex than that. Anyway, is there any automatic solution like when entries are with wrong datatypes ?

Comment: `Well, it's little bit more complex than that.`  That's one way to call spaghetti code.  A container has a ControlAdded event.  You can use that as a way to map your control to the error provider.

Comment: LarsTech : That's one way to call the pretentious guy able to judge something without having any idea on how it is. Here is how it works man. There is a service that generates fields from a database to create dynamic forms... Forms that can write exchange data on any table on the database of any form. This is my part. There is already an existing part that assembles these generated fields to some forms. This second part is handled by another team and I do not have freedom to change as expected... If you have an answer, I will be thankfull to you. However you can keep spaghetti for you. Thanks

Comment: But your question doesn't make sense.  `When I type some wrong data in fields, the ErrorProvider shows a red ico automatically.`  But then you add `controls are created in a separate process and do not have access to the ErrorProvider.`  Well, which is it?

Comment: The error provider is a devexpress control that is bound to the same datatable as the fields. And it is able (downstream) to detect wrong entries. It shows automatically the error icons on the fields. The aspect doesn't work with empty fields

Comment: I'm not your down voter, but now we are dealing with a DevExpress Error Provider?  Where is that information in your post?  That would seem like an important detail since you are painting a picture in your comments that you have no access to the form where the Error Provider is currently residing.  Maybe the "other team" should provide this service since they have the form, the controls, and the error provider.

Comment: you can set a separate class that returns error when get() property is set to ""

Comment: also you don't have to seterror since errorprovider can be hooked to textbox

Comment: [you can set a separate class that returns error when get() property is set to ""] Can you detail this idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom class in your case:

```
Public Class customdatatable
        Implements IDXDataErrorInfo

        Private _value As String
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
        End Sub
        Public Property C1() As String
            Get
                Return _value
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _value = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Public Sub GetPropertyError(ByVal name As String, ByVal errorinfo As ErrorInfo) _
          Implements IDXDataErrorInfo.GetPropertyError
            If (name = "C1" And C1 = "") Then
                errorinfo.ErrorText = String.Format("Empty value")
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Sub GetError(ByVal errorinfo As ErrorInfo) Implements IDXDataErrorInfo.GetError
        End Sub
    End Class
```

then apply it to your form:

```
Dim DT = New customdatatable With {.C1 = 5} ''GetDT()
TextEdit1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("EditValue", DT ,"C1", True))
DxErrorProvider1.DataSource = DT
```

---

If you don't care to lose focus control on your textfield just use this in your main.

```
Dim field2 = GetDT()
TextEdit1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("EditValue", field2,"C1", True))
DxErrorProvider1.DataSource = field2
```